# How do I handle missing XML nodes when working with let in LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a very large XML document that has some missing nodes.

Good XML:

```
<wd:Job_Family wd:Descriptor="Research/Extension">
<wd:Home_Phone wd:Descriptor="+1 (555) 555-0731">
  <wd:ID wd:type="WID">89bfac800b6b41da94e1d1a22b14e66a</wd:ID>
</wd:Home_Phone>
<wd:Home_Address wd:Descriptor="1 Beverly Dr">
```

Bad XML:

```
 <wd:Job_Family wd:Descriptor="Research/Extension">
     ***MISSING ***
<wd:Home_Address wd:Descriptor="1 Beverly Dr">
```

The way I had been selecting the data was like this:

```
List<Employee> employee = new List<Employee>();
try
{
    // Get the xml file as stream  
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(outputFileNameAndPath);

    // Read the whole contents and return as a string  
    string xmlString = reader.ReadToEnd();

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
    XNamespace wd = "urn:com.something.report/Worker_ID_Data_-_Store";

    IEnumerable<XElement> worker = doc.Descendants(wd + "Report_Entry");

    var query = (from x in doc.Descendants(wd + "Report_Entry")

                 let jobFamilyAttribute = x.Element(wd + "Job_Family_Group").Attributes(wd + "Descriptor").FirstOrDefault()

                 select new Employee
                 {
                    JobFamily = jobFamilyAttribute.Value
                 });
    employee.AddRange(query);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.Error("An error occurred while trying to parse the XML: " + ex);
}
return employee;
```

That works great.  There are some additional nodes I select, but for simplicity sake, this is enough.

Now, when I try to select a node that is missing (which might be 1 out of 1000 records), I get errors for Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

That makes sense, since the node being selected isn't there.
After reading many postings, it looks like I should do a ternary operator to account for the null parent.  Something like this:

```
let homePhoneAttribute = x.Element(wd + "Home_Phone") == null ? "" : x.Element(wd + "Home_Phone").Attributes(wd + "Descriptor").FirstOrDefault()
```

That isn't quite right:
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute'

Even if I cast it to a string or object, it compiles, but then I only get the very first value for all records when I addrange:

```
let homePhoneAttribute = x.Element(wd + "Home_Phone") == null ? (string)"" : x.Element(wd + "Home_Phone").Attributes(wd + "Descriptor").FirstOrDefault().Value
```

So, my long winded question is, how do I properly cast and account for null nodes while still being able to select with a let?

I think it has to be some kind of `DefaultIfEmpty()` casting?

Comment: You get the first record because you have `FirstOrDefault()` on the query.  Would a slightly different query work - `let homePhoneAttribute = (string)x.Element(wd + "Home_Phone") == null ? String.Empty : x.Element(wd + "Home_Phone").Attributes(wd + "Descriptor");` - note this will give you a collection, which you can then do with what you want.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the help...  that doesn't quite work either.  Still casting issues:  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute>'

Comment: Perhaps this:  `let homePhoneAttribute = (string)x.Element(wd + "Home_Phone") == null ? null : x.Element(wd + "Home_Phone").Attributes(wd + "Descriptor");` - replace the `String.Empty` with `null`.  Though that might cause downstream problems.  Perhaps instead of `null`, use `new IEnumerable<XAttribute>();` or something similar?

Comment: Hi Tim - I still need to select the `XAttribute Value. homePhoneAttribute.FirstOrDefault().Value.  `As soon as I do that, it breaks the casting again.  If I don't use FirstOrDefault(), I get this `'IEnumerable<XAttribute>' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<XAttribute>' could be found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expression :

```
let homePhoneAttribute = (string)x.Elements(wd + "Home_Phone")
                                  .Attributes(wd + "Descriptor")
                                  .FirstOrDefault()
```

By using `x.Elements()` instead of the singular form `Element()` you can avoid exception in case the element is not found. And then, by casting `FirstOrDefault()` return value to `string` you can avoid exception in case the return value is `null`.

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LIEfwo)</kbd>**

The demo shows that `homePhoneAttribute` variable simply contains empty string when `wd:Home_Phone` element is missing. No exception thrown.

**UPDATE :**

If you want multiple attributes value (`List<string>`) instead of just just the first, you can modify the above LINQ a bit as follow :

```
let homePhoneAttribute = x.Elements(wd + "Home_Phone")
                          .Attributes(wd + "Descriptor")
                          .Select(o => o.Value)
                          .ToList()
```

Comment: You are right that it casts properly, but it it also only selects the first phone number:
                             `select new Employee
                             {
                                 JobFamily = jobFamilyAttribute.Value,
                                 HomePhone = homePhoneAttribute,
                             });
                employee.AddRange(query);`

Comment: @MattKnight check **update** section above. I assumed you want `List<string>` as value of ` HomePhone` property

Comment: I appreciate your help.  When I use .ToList(), I still need to specify something in the select:   `select new Employee
                             {
                                 JobFamily = jobFamilyAttribute.Value,
                                 HomePhone = homePhoneAttribute need something here,
                             });`   I need to select the XAttribute.Value, like I am doing for JobFamily.    If I use FirstorDefault(), every record is assigned the same phone number.  Maybe I should add some more data and work with you on .Net Fiddle?

Comment: @MattKnight sure, providing .NET fiddle containing base codes and representative sample data would make it easy for people to help

Comment: Your answer did the trick,  `let homePhoneAttribute = x.Elements(wd + "Home_Phone")
                           .Attributes(wd + "Descriptor")
                           .Select(o => o.Value)
                           .ToList()`  And then in the select I used `HomePhone = homePhoneAttribute.FirstOrDefault(),`   Thanks for your help!